# Escape quotes while splitting string in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript code to parse CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)

Simple and straight, if I have a string like: 1001,"abc, xyz", 34

I want it to split into 3 strings not 4. If I use split(','), it splits abc and xyz into two strings however I want it as a single string as it is inside double quotes.

So my final outcome should be:

```
1001
abc, xyz
34
```

What should I use inside split(), so that I can get expected output?

Comment: Someone else's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data

Comment: @emurano It helps the moderators if you flag the question as duplicate, rather than just commenting.